# Drawing lines on a panel

Tags: c#, drawing, lines

I try to make a graphics.
When I click on my label, I want to draw a line. It works, it draw my line but at the last point there is another line going at the left top corner.. I don't know why.

(It's useless, but it's for another project, I try to understand how works the drawing)

Here's my code :

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    Pen myPen = new Pen(Color.Blue);
    Graphics g = null;
    int start_x = 0, start_y;
    Point[] points = new Point[1000];
    int test = 0;

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        start_y = canvas.Height / 2;
        points[0] = new Point (start_x,start_y);
        myPen.Width = 1;
    }

    private void drawLine()
    {

        g.DrawLines(myPen, points);
    }

    private void incrementation_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        test = test + 1;
        incrementation.Text = test.ToString();
        if(test == 1)
        {
            points[1] = new Point(100, start_y);
        }
        if (test == 2)
        {
            points[test] = new Point(200, 90),new Point(220, 10);
        }
        if (test == 3)
        {
            points[test] = new Point(220, 10);
            drawLine();
        }

    }

    private void canvas_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        g = canvas.CreateGraphics();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A couple of issues.

- You don't assign any values to points after `points[3]`.
- Point is a structure and will have a value of [0,0] at all further elements
- so your lines go there.. (all 996 of them ;-)

There is more you should change:

- Do the drawing in the `Paint` event or trigger it from there.
- Do not **store** the `Paint e.Grahpics` object. You can pass it out to use it, but don't try to hold on to it.
- After adding or changing the `points`, write `canvas.Invalidate()` to trigger the `Paint` event. This will make your drawing persistent.

To learn about persistent drawing minimize & restore the form!

- Also you should use a `List<Point>` instead of an array. This lets you add `Points` without having to decide on the number of `Points` you want to support..

To create a new `Point` you write something like this:

```
points.Add(new Point(100, start_y) );
```

To draw you then use this format in the `Paint` event::

```
e.Graphics.DrawLines(myPen, points.toArray());
```

Comment: Thank you it was because all of my array was [0,0], but i don't manage to make a list of point. It draw me a red cross

Answer (score 1):

In the constructor you're filling first point as

```
points[0] = new Point (start_x,start_y);
```

At this moment, `start_x = 0` (since you're not assigned anything else to it after declaration `int start_x = 0`).

Then in `incrementation_Click` you're assigning `points[1]`, `points[2]` and `points[3]`, but you don't changing anywhere in your code `points[0]`.

So when you calling `g.DrawLines` - first point will always be `(0, canvas.Height / 2)`

Aside from this:

1. You don't need to create graphics explicitly in `_Paint` event handler since it can accessed as `e.Graphics`.
2. It's better to move all paintings into `canvas_Paint` like:

```
private void canvas_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
{
    e.Graphics.DrawLines(myPen, points);
}
```

and in your `_Click` handler instead of calling `drawLine` you should only call `canvas.Refresh()`